# Inserting Google Maps into my Web Page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

I am creating a web app. where I want be able to incorporate Google Maps into 1 of my pages.
From what I have read in other places, the easiest think is to place a web browser onto the form but there is no 'Web Browser' in the tool-box.

What I am trying to do is to insert a location into a textbox(ie. London) and insert a type of sport(ieCycling) and the resultant map shows up. Is there any other way in doing this in C# other than using the web browser tool.

Here is my code:

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string sport = txtSport.Text;
        string location = txtLocation.Text;



        try
        {
            StringBuilder queryAddrress = new StringBuilder();
            queryAddrress.Append("https://maps.google.ie/");

            if (sport != string.Empty)
            {
                queryAddrress.Append(sport+","+"+");


            }

            if (location != string.Empty)
            {
                queryAddrress.Append(location + "," + "+");


            }


            Panel1.Navigate(queryAddrress.ToString());


        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(),"Error");
        }


    } protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string sport = txtSport.Text;
        string location = txtLocation.Text;



        try
        {
            StringBuilder queryAddrress = new StringBuilder();
            queryAddrress.Append("https://maps.google.ie/");

            if (sport != string.Empty)
            {
                queryAddrress.Append(sport+","+"+");


            }

            if (location != string.Empty)
            {
                queryAddrress.Append(location + "," + "+");


            }


            Panel1.Navigate(queryAddrress.ToString());


        }
```

I tried to put the address into a panel but this is clearly wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are very confused and mixing [ASP.NET Web Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) with [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms).

Specifically, `MessageBox.Show()` would open a Windows message box, not a browser window. And it would happen on the server side for whatever user your web server runs as. Probably not the desired  intention. Also, you can't "put a web browser" onto a page. There is a WebBrowser control for Windows Forms, which embeds a minified version of Internet Explorer into a Windows application. But again, probably not what you want.

ASP.NET can be used as if it were just a normal HTML site. So find some [Google Maps tutorials](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/72644?hl=en) for HTML and follow those.